# Controller function runs every time when page is refreshed using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a single button. When I clicked on the button then it's called the function demo inside my testcontroller.I have to call the view page called as `createsection` also I have to call the model(For sending an email which is working).

After clicking on the button now I am on `createsection` page but when I fresh the page It's again calling demo function in the controller.

I just need on a single click to call view and also call the model in the background. User will get the view page and model can send the email.

**welcome.php**

```
<?php echo form_open('testcontroller/demo'); ?>
<button name="clicked">click me</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**testcontroller/demo**

```
class testcontroller extends CI_Controller {    
public function demo(){
    $email=$this->session->userdata('email');

    $this->load->view('createsection');

    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $id=$this->user_model->new_user($email);//passing email id in model to send the email

    //more code here..............
}
}
```

**createsection (view page)**

The user will get this page after clicking on the button.

```
   <?php echo form_open('testcontroller/confirm'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="code">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Whenever you load the `testcontroller/demo` page, the `demo` function will be executed. Why do you want to refresh the page? What functionality are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Because you have load view page and not change controller after refresh u have still in same controller that's why again calling same controller.

Comment: @NeilPatrao, In view (createsection) page I am taking the confirmation code which user got on email. If I  refresh the page then emails will get continue.

Comment: @LomeshKelwadkar, Yes I am on the same controller. I just need on a single click to call view and also call the model. User will get the view page and model can send the email

Comment: You need to explain more. Is this all the code you have? Where is the code for the controller of `welcome.php` page? How many controllers d you have?

Comment: @NeilPatrao, I updated it. welcome.php is the name of the view. The user will get first welcome.php page. I have only one controller and one model

Comment: Where is the code that loads the `welcome.php` view? And where is the code for building the forms? You need to post everything, otherwise how are we supposed to understand your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, when you are refreshing the page `newuser` model function executing multiple times. You can avoid these problem by redirecting

```
class testcontroller extends CI_Controller {

    public function demo(){
        $email = $this->session->userdata('email');

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        // passing email id in model to send the email
        $id=$this->user_model->new_user($email); 

        redirect('testcontroller/demo_view/');
        //more code here..............
    }

    public function demo_view(){
        $this->load->view('createsection');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.ubm, Your code is working perfectly for me and thank you for understanding my question.Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Make this change in you controller and run the testcontroller
it will open the welcome.php page Then you can find the confirm form Click on the submit button it will work

```
 class testcontroller extends CI_Controller {    


        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('welcome');
        }

        public function demo() {
            $this->load->view('createsection');
        }
        public function confirm(){

            $email=$this->session->userdata('email');

            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $return = $this->user_model->new_user($email);         
        }
     }
```

Comment: After clicked on submit button I have to call confirm function?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Mr.Gss, Thanks for the reply.Above solution is working for me.upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question is:

A function inside a `Controller` is not invoked on UI events but when the page is loaded.

For example, if you load the page `testcontroller/demo`, the `demo()` function is executed. If you load the page `testcontroller/confirm`, the `confirm()` function is executed. Of course, these functions should exist otherwise you would get a 404 not found error.